# How to display the total number of users? Angular 2

Tags: angular

How can I display the total number of users? At the moment I have displays in this form:

> Number of users: 0.
>
> Number of users: 1.
>
> Number of users: 2.
>
> Number of users: 3.
>
> Number of users: 4.
>
> Number of users: 5.
>
> Number of users: 6.
>
> Number of users: 7.
>
> Number of users: 8.
>
> Number of users: 9.
>
> Number of users: 10.
>
> Number of users: 11.
>
> Number of users: 12.

```
 <p class="category" *ngFor="let user of users; let i = index">Number of users: {{i}}. {{item}}</p>
```

Need to be displayed in this form:

> Number of users: 13

**Man, people, you got it wrong. I have a duplicate line every time.**

Comment: start your index from 1 by adding

Comment: type so? {{i+1}}

Comment: use {{i+1}}.Number of users: {{i+1}}

Comment: You misunderstood. I have a duplicate row every time

Comment: I thought you need to display total number of user so use it 
  Number of user = users.length (need to define data type of user) 
or users?.length (no need to define data type of user)

Comment: can you provide your array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to use *ngFor directive if you just need to show the total number of users, Instead you can do something like this:

```
<p>Number of users: {{users.length}}</p>
```

Cheers.

Comment: You should probably check if the users even exist before getting a length of it. `<p *ngIf="users">`or use optional `?` operator `{{ users?.length }}`

Answer (score 1):

Why not to simply  use -

```
{{users.length}}
```

You can simply use `length` prop over the array instead of using `ngFor`.